# Jquery DataTable sorting not working when using ajax to populate data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have been trying to use **ajax** to populate data in a table on page load. The data is loaded fine in my table but The issue I'm facing is with sorting and pagination of **jQuery**. as when ever i click its sorting arrow, it shows no data available in the table. My table code is:

```html
{{-- /Table Starts form here --}}
<table id="DtAdminAttendance" class="table table-striped custom-table mb-0 datatable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            {{-- <th style="display: none">tbl_index</th> --}}
            <th>Emp ID - Name</th>
            <th>Date </th>
            <th>Punch In</th>
            <th>Punch Out</th>
            <th>Worked Hours</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th class="text-right">Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    
    <tbody id="atn-tbody">
        {{-- table data goes here --}}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

My **ajax** for this table is:

```html
<script>
    //for displaying table data department
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // var table = $('#DtAdminAttendance').DataTable();
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "fetch-Attendance",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                $('tbody').html("");
                $.each(response.Attendance_list, function (key, employee) {
                    if (employee.status == "Absent") 
                    {
                        $('tbody').append(
                            `<tr>\
                                <td style="display: none"> ${employee.id} </td>\
                                <td> ${employee.employeeID} - ${employee.name} </td>\
                                <td> ${employee.date} </td>\
                                <td> ${employee.Punch_in} </td>\
                                <td> ${(employee.Punch_Out == null ? '-' : employee.Punch_Out)} </td>\
                                <td> ${employee.totalhours} </td>\
                                <td class="badge  badge-danger"> ${employee.status} </td>\

                                <td class="text-right">
                                    <div class="dropdown dropdown-action">
                                        <a href="#" class="action-icon dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                                            <i class="material-icons">more_vert</i>
                                        </a>

                                        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                                            <button type="button" class="dropdown-item edtAtn" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit_Attendance" value="  ${employee.id}">
                                                <i class="fa fa-pencil m-r-5"></i> Edit
                                            </button>

                                            <button type="button" class="dropdown-item dltAtn" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete_Attendance" value="${employee.id}">
                                                <i class="fa fa-trash-o m-r-5"></i> Delete
                                            </button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>\
                                </td>\
                            </tr>`);
                    }
                    else if (employee.status == "Present") 
                    {
                        $('tbody').append(
                            `<tr>\
                                <td style="display: none"> ${employee.id} </td>\
                                <td> ${employee.employeeID} '-' {employee.name}</td>\
                                <td> ${employee.date}</td>\
                                <td> ${employee.Punch_in}</td>\
                                <td> ${(employee.Punch_Out == null ? '-' : employee.Punch_Out)}</td>\
                                <td> ${employee.totalhours}</td>\
                                <td class="badge  badge-success"> ${employee.status}</td>

                                <td class="text-right">
                                    <div class="dropdown dropdown-action">
                                        <a href="#" class="action-icon dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                                            <i class="material-icons">more_vert</i>
                                        </a>

                                        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                                            <button type="button" class="dropdown-item edtAtn" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit_Attendance" value="${employee.id}" >
                                                <i class="fa fa-pencil m-r-5"></i> Edit
                                            </button>

                                            <button type="button" class="dropdown-item dltAtn" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete_Attendance" value="${employee.id}">
                                                <i class="fa fa-trash-o m-r-5"></i> Delete
                                            </button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>\
                                </td>\
                            </tr>`);
                    }
                    else if (employee.status == "Late") 
                    {
                        $('tbody').append(
                            `<tr>\
                                <td style="display: none"> ${employee.id} </td>\
                                <td> ${employee.employeeID} '-' ${employee.name} </td>\
                                <td> ${employee.date}</td>\
                                <td> ${employee.Punch_in}</td>\
                                <td> ${(employee.Punch_Out == null ? '-' : employee.Punch_Out)}</td>\
                                <td> ${employee.totalhours}</td>\
                                <td class="badge  badge-warning"> ${employee.status} </td>

                                <td class="text-right">
                                    <div class="dropdown dropdown-action">
                                        <a href="#" class="action-icon dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                                            <i class="material-icons">more_vert</i>
                                        </a>

                                        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                                            <button type="button" class="dropdown-item edtAtn" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit_Attendance" value="${employee.id}">
                                                <i class="fa fa-pencil m-r-5"></i> Edit
                                            </button>

                                            <button type="button" class="dropdown-item dltAtn" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete_Attendance" value="${employee.id}">
                                                <i class="fa fa-trash-o m-r-5"></i> Delete
                                            </button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>\
                                </td>\
                            </tr>`);
                    } 
                    else if (employee.status == "Unpaid Halfday") 
                    {
                        $('tbody').append(
                            `<tr>\
                                <td style="display: none"> ${employee.id} </td>\
                                <td> ${employee.employeeID} '-' ${employee.name} </td>\
                                <td> ${employee.date}</td>\
                                <td> ${employee.Punch_in}</td>\
                                <td> ${(employee.Punch_Out == null ? '-' : employee.Punch_Out)} </td>\
                                <td> ${employee.totalhours}</td>\
                                <td class="badge  badge-info"> ${employee.status} </td>

                                <td class="text-right">
                                    <div class="dropdown dropdown-action">
                                        <a href="#" class="action-icon dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                                            <i class="material-icons">more_vert</i>
                                        </a>

                                        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">

                                        <button type="button" class="dropdown-item edtAtn" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit_Attendance" value="${employee.id}">
                                            <i class="fa fa-pencil m-r-5"></i> Edit
                                        </button>

                                        <button type="button" class="dropdown-item dltAtn" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete_Attendance" value="${employee.id}" >
                                            <i class="fa fa-trash-o m-r-5"></i> Delete
                                        </button>
                                    </div></div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>`);
                    }
                });
                $('#DtAdminAttendance').DataTable();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Now when I go to the page it loads the table rows:

[image: normal call]

But when I sort using any of the column it shows me no data available in table:

[image: no data available]

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Is this a PHP problem, where the data is not sent to the browser in the expected format, or a JS problem, where the browser does not handle that data properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my tests, your issue isn't reproducible. It works fine on my side.

[JS Fiddle: OP's test code](https://jsfiddle.net/theAccountant/9javuLkq/9/)

Nonetheless, your source code could use some improvement and probably this may resolve your issue.

***Instead of manually manipulating the HTML table, use the dataTable API to automatically generate the table.***

[JS Fiddle: Improved source code](https://jsfiddle.net/theAccountant/wp9y6g0z/25/)

##### HTML

```html
<table id="DtAdminAttendance" class="table table-striped custom-table mb-0 datatable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>tbl_index</th>
            <th>Emp ID - Name</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Punch In</th>
            <th>Punch Out</th>
            <th>Worked Hours</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th class="text-right">Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="atn-tbody">
    </tbody>
</table>
```

##### JavaScript

*Change the `ajax: {url: '...'}` according to your needs. I.e: '/fetch-Attendance'*.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#DtAdminAttendance").DataTable({
        scrollX: true,
        autoWidth: false,
        ajax: {
            type: "GET",
            url: "https://run.mocky.io/v3/9ef15223-a192-4f3c-a2fb-843048cb31dc",
            dataType: "JSON",
            dataSrc: "Attendance_list",
            async: true,
        },
        columns: [
            {data: "id"},
            {
                data: "name", "fnCreatedCell": function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {
                    $(nTd).html(`${oData.employeeID + "-" + oData.name}`);
                }
            },
            {data: "date"},
            {data: "Punch_in"},
            {data: "Punch_Out"},
            {data: "totalhours"},
            {
                data: "status", "fnCreatedCell": function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {
                    const statusBtn = $("<span class='badge'></span>");
                    let badgeColor = "badge-secondary";

                    switch (oData.status) {
                        case "Absent":
                            badgeColor = "badge-danger";
                            break;
                        case "Present":
                            badgeColor = "badge-success";
                            break;
                        case "Late":
                            badgeColor = "badge-warning";
                            break;
                        case "Unpaid Halfday":
                            badgeColor = "badge-info";
                            break;

                    }

                    statusBtn.addClass(badgeColor);
                    statusBtn.text(oData.status);

                    $(nTd).html(statusBtn.get(0));
                }
            },
            {
                data: null, "fnCreatedCell": function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {
                    const actionBtn = $(`
                    <div class="d-inline-block text-right">
                        <div class="dropdown dropdown-action">
                            <a href="#" class="action-icon dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                                <i class="material-icons">more_vert</i>
                            </a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                                <button style="cursor: pointer;" type="button" class="dropdown-item edtAtn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit_Attendance" value="${oData.id}">
                                    <i class="fa fa-pencil m-r-5"></i>
                                    Edit
                                </button>
                                <button style="cursor: pointer;" type="button" class="dropdown-item dltAtn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete_Attendance" value="${oData.id}">
                                    <i class="fa fa-trash-o m-r-5"></i>
                                    Delete
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                `);

                    $(nTd).html(actionBtn.get(0));
                },
                orderable: false,
                searchable: false
            }
        ],
        columnDefs: [
            {
                "targets": [0],
                "visible": false
            },
            {
                "defaultContent": "-",
                "targets": "_all"
            }

        ]
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

After adding the **jQuery** ([script](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js)) and **dataTable** ([script](https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js), [style](https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css)) references to the HTML file, you should add the following code to the script to sort the **dataTable**. For the project to work properly, you should add the script you will run to the last file. As far as I've commented, there's no problem applying the dataTable style. You probably didn't add the *dataTable script reference* to the project. Retest the project using the references in the template below and the commands in the `<script>` element.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <table id="DtAdminAttendance" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <!-- Something -->
    </table>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#DtAdminAttendance').DataTable({
                order: [
                    [3, 'desc'],
                    [0, 'asc']
                ]
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It would be a great help if you can explain a little bit more, i am using laravel and all my js and css files are getting load from there. this one is my custom script. now when i have added this code in my script  it is giving me error  **DataTables warning: table id=DtAdminAttendance - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/3 **

Comment: i have included it as follow  `code`  $(document).ready(function () {

  $('#DtAdminAttendance').DataTable({
   order: [
                    [3, 'desc'],
                    [0, 'asc']
                ]
   });    my ajax is below this one

Comment: I added that line to show it. Reference is [here](https://datatables.net/reference/api/order()).

Comment: I don't know Laravel and php structure. If rendering as in ASP.NET, you may need to specify the scripts I specified in a field like `@section scripts{}`. If you have root layout, add direct script references there. When this page is rendered, your scripts will already be loaded on the page.

Comment: Or if the data is coming to the page dynamically, the problem may be in the backend, not the frontend.

Comment: Also the question is not clear. You will get a faster response if you revise this post as if you are trying to sort by pulling data on a single line. If it's a PHP-related post, add the `php`  tag to the post. For this reason, I gave this answer thinking that the data was pulled from the backend in a healthy way.

Comment: sure thanks. i have updated the tags lets see if anybody can answer it . thanks for help , appreciate it

Comment: I edited the jQuery code and submitted it for moderator approval. Using the ``${variable_name}`` format to define multiline variables with parameters in JavaScript makes the code more readable. This is called using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). There is a meaningless line of code in the dynamic html expression in the line where the `else if (employee.status == "Unpaid Halfday")` code is passed;  I don't understand why you wrote this: `</div></div>`